# Is there a specific rule or theorem to do differentiation for integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have seen many problems while doing my homework asking me to do a differentiation for an integral. How could I solve such problems? For example, how would I solve the following definite integral
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_5^{3x^2} (4-x^2)^4\,dx
$$

Comment: Could you tell us an example of the problems?

Comment: question edited

Comment: Is it $\frac{d}{dx}\int_5^{3x^2} (4-x^2)^4dx$ ?

Comment: The [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) plus the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) is the way to go.

Comment: Could you expalin, please ?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to Leibniz's rule, which is derived from the fundamental definition of Riemann integration.
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\int\limits_{v\left(x\right)}^{u\left(x\right)}f\left(x\right)\:dx & = f\left(u\left(x\right)\right)\frac{du\left(x\right)}{dx}-f\left(v\left(x\right)\right)\frac{dv\left(x\right)}{dx}\tag{1},
\end{align*}
but you could also say that
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\int\limits_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)\:dx & = \int\limits_{a}^{b} \frac{\partial{f}\left(x\right)}{\partial x}\:dx,\tag{2}
\end{align*}
and so on with many such identities. With this particular problem you could solve it simply like this:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\int\limits_5^{3x^2}\left(4-x^2\right)^4\:dx & =\left(4-\left(3x^2\right)^2\right)^4\cdot 6x-0=\boxed{6x\left(4-\left(3x^2\right)^2\right)^4,}\tag{3}
\end{align}
using $\left(1\right)$, and using $\left(2\right)$ we arrive at
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\int\limits_5^{3x^2}\left(4-x^2\right)^4\:dx & =\int\limits_5^{3x^2}4\left(4-x^2\right)^3\left(-2x\right)\:dx=-8\int\limits_5^{3x^2}x\left(4-x^2\right)^3\:dx \\
& = -8\int\limits_5^{3x^2}x\left\{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{3}\left(\begin{matrix}3 \\n\end{matrix}\right)4^n\left(-x^2\right)^{3-n}\right\}\:dx \\
& =-8\int\limits_5^{3x^2}x\left\{\left(-x^2\right)^3+12\left(-x^2\right)^2+48\left(-x^2\right)+\left(64\right)\right\}\:dx \\
& = -8\int\limits_5^{3x^2}x\left\{-x^6+12x^4-48x^2+64\right\}\:dx \\
& = -8\int\limits_5^{3x^2}\left(-x^7+12x^5-48x^3+64x\right)\:dx \\
& = -8\bigg[\frac{-x^8}{8}+2x^6-12x^4+32x^2\bigg]_5^{3x^2} \\
& = \bigg[x^8-16x^6+96x^4-256x^2\bigg]_5^{3x^2}, \\
\end{align}
and I'll leave you to tidy it up. The degrees seem to match, however, so I'm assuming I did the second part right despite not doing it by hand to check.